# push on SelectAll Stream

Tags: rust, rust-futures

I would like to have a struct for handling some streams. All streams share the same Item. The logic is the following: I need to create a unique stream that contains all items that came from all other streams. I need also to add "new" stream to the "main" stream. I don't care from which stream the next item comes from.

For doing that, I see there's the [`select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/select_all/fn.select_all.html) function that should do the logic described above.

```rust
pub struct WsPool {
    merge: Arc<Mutex<SelectAll<Box<dyn Stream<Item=MyItem> + Send + 'static>>>>,
}

impl WsPool {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            merge: Arc::new(Mutex::new(SelectAll::new())),
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&self, s: Box<dyn Stream<Item = MyItem> + Send + 'static>) {
        let mut merge  = self.merge.lock().unwrap();

        merge.push(s);
    }

    pub async fn process(&self) {
        loop {
            let mut merge = self.merge.lock().unwrap();
            let item = merge.await.next();
        }
    }
}
```

But I receive these errors:

```
error[E0277]: `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, futures::stream::SelectAll<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>>` is not a future
  --> src/ws_pool.rs:30:24
   |
30 |             let item = merge.await.next();
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, futures::stream::SelectAll<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>>` is not a future
   |
   = help: the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, futures::stream::SelectAll<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>>`
note: required by `futures::Future::poll`
  --> /home/allevo/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/future/future.rs:99:5
   |
99 |     fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: `(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)` cannot be unpinned
  --> src/ws_pool.rs:17:40
   |
17 |             merge: Arc::new(Mutex::new(SelectAll::new())),
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)`
   |
   = note: consider using `Box::pin`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Stream` for `Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>`
note: required by `futures::stream::SelectAll::<St>::new`
  --> /home/allevo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.17/src/stream/select_all.rs:47:5
   |
47 |     pub fn new() -> Self {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: the method `push` exists for struct `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, futures::stream::SelectAll<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/ws_pool.rs:24:15
    |
24  |           merge.push(s);
    |                 ^^^^ method cannot be called on `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, futures::stream::SelectAll<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /home/allevo/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:172:1
    |
172 | / pub struct Box<
173 | |     T: ?Sized,
174 | |     #[unstable(feature = "allocator_api", issue = "32838")] A: Allocator = Global,
175 | | >(Unique<T>, A);
    | |________________- doesn't satisfy `_: futures::Stream`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = MyItem> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>: futures::Stream`
```

What am I doing wrong? Otherwise how can I store multiple streams and iterate over them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is a simple mixup. You want to `await` the *next* value, not the stream itself:

```
let item = merge.next().await;
```

---

The resulting errors are all because `SelectAll<Box<dyn Stream + Send + 'static>>` does not implement `Stream`. If you look at the [`impl Stream for SelectAll`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/struct.SelectAll.html#impl-Stream), it is constrained that the inner stream type implements [`Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html).

You can fix this by adding it to the bounds:

```
use std::marker::Unpin;
                                               // vvvvv
Arc<Mutex<SelectAll<Box<dyn Stream<Item=MyItem> + Unpin + Send + 'static>>>>
```

Or a better solution is to just pin the streams:

```
use std::pin::Pin;
                 // vvv
Arc<Mutex<SelectAll<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item=MyItem> + Send + 'static>>>>>
```

The difference is the latter can accept more `Stream` types. You just have to use [`Box::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.pin) when adding them.

See it working on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=216aeca795c5232b69495843409b283f).